# Access translated property of collection in form

Tags: symfony

I have a form with a collection. My form "PageType" with a collection look like this.

```
$builder->add('sections', 'collection', array(
                        'type'         => new SectionType($this->securityContext, $this->entityManager) ,
                        'allow_add'    => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        'label'        => false,
                        'prototype' => true,
                        'prototype_name' => '__sectionPrototype__',
                        'options'      => array(
                            'label' => false,
                        )
```

And my second form which represents the collection "SectionType" look like this.

```
 ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'title' => array(
                            'field_type' => 'text',
                            'label' => 'title',
                            'attr' => array('class' => 'rte sectionTitle')
                        ),
                        'text' => array(
                            'field_type' => 'textarea',
                            'label' => 'hintText',
                            'attr' => array('class' => 'rte sectionDescription')
                        )
                    )
                ))
```

How can i access from twig the translations fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible. Maybe somebody could correct me if I'm wrong.

`fields` is an option item for `a2lix_translations`. If you would have `Form` object you might be able to do that, but in fact, you have `FormView` which represents built form.

Alternatively, you could pass that `array` via standard return from controller and into your twig. Does that sound good?

Comment: thank you a lot. i realized this via standard return from controller